# How do I loop over the Devanagari Handwritten Digits/Characters Dataset and simultaneously input my data to training and testing sets?

Tags: python

The following is the link to the dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/ashokpant/devanagari-character-dataset
The number of directories and files in each directory are irregular in count. I find no possible way to iterate through each directory also considering how the names of each directory are not consecutive.

Comment: It is necessary to provide all important information within the question itself, not by an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume something like this can be implemented, after going through the dataset link:

```
import os
import numpy as np

X_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(10):
    dir="DirectoryName/Train/digit_{0}".format(i)
    print(i,":",len(os.listdir(dir)))
    for j in os.listdir(dir):
        X_train.append(plt.imread(dir+"/"+j))
        y_train.append(i)

X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
```

Similarly for the characters directory - train/test